# Why are these two JavaScript Date objects not the same?

Tags: javascript

I`m a beginner reading a tutorial about Dates in JavaScript, and it gives this example to compare the time between two events.

I don't really understand why firstDate and var secondDate wouldn't be the exact same time? does the new Date object in var secondDate only take the time once doEvent is triggered, whereas firstDate takes the time with window.onload?

Also, why would the variable firstDate not have the "var" tag, while variable secondDate does? would that be just a typo by the author, or is it significant in some way?

```
var firstDate;
window.onload=startTimer;

function startTimer(){
 firstDate = new Date();
 document.getElementById("date").onclick=doEvent;
}

function doEvent() {
 var secondDate = new Date();
 alert((secondDate - firstDate) / 1000);
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse new Date object in var secondDate only take the time once doEvent is triggered, because writing a method in succession of another method does not execute it, rather it is executed on the event it is bind to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is exactly correct. `firstDate` is the time when the `window.load` event fires, and `secondDate` is the time when the element with id `date` is clicked.

---

In re: your edit, there **is** a `var` to go with the `firstDate` as well - it's outside of the scope of `startTimer`. It is *not* a typo. `firstDate` needs to be defined outside of the scope of the `startTimer` and `doEvent` functions so that it has a meaningful value inside of the `doEvent` function.

It might be useful for you to read up on [JavaScript scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: o.k., thanks. Can you answer the second question I just added to the OP about why firstDate has no var tag whereas the secondDate does?

Comment: thank you. why didn`t var secondDate need to be defined outside the scope of the functions?

Comment: @mjmitche: because it does not need to be used outside of `doEvent`.

Comment: thanks, so if firstDate was only defined inside of startTimer, it would have worked in that function, but not in doEvent?  appreciate your help.